# Output of print to file Inside script | Python

Tags: python

I simply need to run the python[V:2.6] script as ./test.py.
The output of print(a) which is 'hello world', should be saved into "file.txt"
how can i do this inside the python script?
I know,

```
./test.py > file.txt
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a = 'hello world'
print(a)
f = open('/root/file.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: you never call input so I would start by fixing that.

Comment: @Padraic I didn't mention input as a function. it is just a string. I changed that to 'hello world'. and it is not duplicate. The duplicate mentioned takes input from user but in this script it is declared inside the script.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a = 'hello world'
f = open('/root/file.txt', 'w')
print >>f, a
```

now "hello world" will be printed in file.txt while running ./test.py
This is simple but might be helpful for python beginners.

Comment: Please don't answer questions with Python2  unless they are explicitly tagged that way. It's way too old to be assuming that's the default.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I disagree. Either Python 2 or Python 3 are possible if no version is specified

Comment: @Mani Could you please add some context to your code?

Comment: @ppperry It's very easy to use the print function in Python 2 (`from __future__ import print_function`), but not the other way around. At any rate, the *question* uses Python 3 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

better solution :
Python print statement got keyword param named **file**

```
print('spam', file=<YOUR FILE>)
```

Comment: Not work for me on python 2.66 Windows 7

Comment: add this :   from __future__ import print_function

Comment: Not working syntax error